# Is there a possibility to add custom years via Ajax on the dropdown?

Tags: jquery, date, datetimepicker

I'm trying to add customs years in intervals like: [2010, 2012, 2015, 2019] to the years dropdown of this Daterangepicker plugin.

http://www.daterangepicker.com/

I've tried to add the years to the select dropdown after the response of my ajax request, but i think there must be another better solution.

```
if(res.status == true){
                    $('body select.yearselect').html('');
                    $.each(res.data, function(index, value){
                        console.log(index); //[2010,2012,2016,2019]
                        $('body select.yearselect').append('<option value="'+index+'">'+index+'</option>');
                    });
                 }
```

But adding direct to the HTML dropdown is not a nice solution, because the months are not correct with the inserted years.
For this reason, i think there must be a solution inside of the plugin, but i didn't find anything where i can change the years dropdown automatically.

Comment: From the docs: `$('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate('03/01/2014')` - why wouldn't that work with your year values?

Comment: @user7290573 It would work if the startDate where 2012 and endDate where 2015. The result will be: 2012...2013...2014..2015. But the problem is i've interval with years like: 2012..2015..2016. Not correlative years.

Comment: Ah, I see - in that case, it doesn't look like the plugin supports the functionality you're after; you're probably best of looking for a different plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I Answer my own question.: This solutions works for me, if someone find another better solution please just let me know!

```
$('#demo').on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
          //do something, like clearing an input
           //$('select.yearselect').html('');
           console.log('show calendar');
           var years = [2011,2012,2014,2017,2019];
            $('.yearselect').empty();
           $.each(years, function(index, value){
             $('.yearselect').append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
           });

        });
```